# Bootstrap dynamic table, appending row (ajax) works but sorting columns doesn't

Tags: ajax, bootstrap-4, datatables, bootstrap-table

Through AJX, I'm able to append a row to the top of my table after a record is successfully stored. 
Before this action:

- my table has 5 items
- pagination also states "Showing 1 to 5 of 5 entries"
- rows being rendered through a Django ListView

After the row is appended to the table:

- 1 see 6 rows (5, plus the one I added)
- Pagination still says "Showing 1 to 5 of 5 entries"

Table sorting works, but once I click on a table column sort. The new row I added is now gone.

My question, how can I add this new row and make the table see it so it can be sorted and pagination shows the new count for all the rows?

Thank in advance

```
// handlebars js Template
<script id="photo-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    <tr id="red-{{id}}">
        <td><img class="chat-img mr-2" src="{{avatar}}" alt="">{{short_name}}</td>
        <td>
            <input type="hidden" id="redurl-{{id}}" value="{{full_url}}" />
            <button data="{{id}}" type="button" class="btn btn-success addlibrary"><i class="ti-plus"></i> To Library</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
</script>

// Generated photoHtml
<tr id="red-124">
    <td><img class="chat-img mr-2" src="https://images.espn.com/image.jpg" alt="">Testing</td>
    <td>
        <input type="hidden" id="redurl-124" value="https://www.espn.com" />
        <button data="124" type="button" class="btn btn-success addlibrary"><i class="ti-plus"></i> To Library</button>
    </td>
</tr>


//AJAX SUCCESS
success: function (response) {
    var resp_obj = response;

    var photoTmplScript = $("#photo-template").html();
    var photoTmpl = Handlebars.compile(photoTmplScript);
    var photoHtml = photoTmpl(resp_obj.data);
    // this works, row is added to table and this is the original question I had. table count not being updated
    //$('#table-body').prepend(photoHtml);

    // prints out the html code for the row correctly with data coming back from AJAX. Reference above for created html code
    console.log(photoHtml);

    var table = $('#scroll-vertical-datatable').DataTable();
    // row is added to table blank, photoHTML is not being added to the DataTable, table count is updated and reflects new row
    table.row.add(photoHtml).draw();
}
```

Comment: Update: I was able to append the row and pagination is now showing the correct total count of rows. I'm using this:
var table = $('#table-id').DataTable();
table.row.add(tableHtml).draw();

tableHtml is a variable with correct html representing the whole row with cells and data. Yet. the row being appended is an empty row. 

So row is being added, pagination is updated to reflect the new row but the row being added is empty but i'm passing the data draw function valid html of the row I want to add.

Comment: It would be worth while to add the code you are using, to show us what your talking about.

Comment: updated with comments above, hope that helps and my question is making sense